# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0*0) in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am trying to parse data in UI from the firebase in this project.But I got a problem as my app will run. It gives an error as "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)" when the next view controller is trying to show. Plzz help me sort out this problem.The code is given as:

```
import Foundation

class Post {
private var _caption: String!
 private var _imageUrl: String!
 private var _likes: Int!
 private var _postKey: String!

var caption: String {
    return _caption
}

var imageUrl: String {
    return _imageUrl
}

var likes: Int {
    return _likes     //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)
}

var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}

init(caption: String, imageUrl: String, likes: Int) {
    self._caption = caption
    self._imageUrl = caption
    self._likes = likes
}

init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

    self._postKey = postKey

    if let caption = postData["caption"] as? String {
        self._caption = caption
    }
    if let imageUrl = postData["imageUrl"] as? String {
        self._imageUrl = imageUrl
    }
    if let likes = postData["likes"] as? Int {
        self._likes = likes
    }

}

}
```

Comment: **Never** declare variables which are initialized through an `init` method as implicit unwrapped optional using a non-optional getter. That causes the error. And backing private variables to get constants is ridiculous in Swift. `let` creates a constant.

Comment: `_likes` is probably `nil`.

Comment: Can you help me out here sir ? It would be a great help @ vadian

Comment: nope, its not nil sir. @ luk2302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over and above my comment the crash occurs if one of the properties is `nil` and the non-optional getter is used.

This `Post` class does the same as in the question, but will never crash

```
class Post {

    let caption: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let likes: Int
    let postKey : String

    init(caption: String, imageUrl: String, likes: Int) {
        self.caption = caption
        self.imageUrl = caption
        self.likes = likes
        self.postKey = ""
    }

    init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        self.postKey = postKey
        self.caption = postData["caption"] as? String ?? ""
        self.imageUrl = postData["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.likes = postData["likes"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}
```

To check if there is an `imageURL`, `postKey` or `caption` just use the `isEmpty` function.

Comment: Thank u sir :) Sir I need to enquire if you have any paid lectures on any websites. I am your regular follower on stackoverflow sir. Is there any possible way to learn from you sir ? @ vadian

Comment: I wasn't aware that there is a follower feature here on SO. I'm afraid, there are no lectures and websites.

Comment: heheh... I am not talking about following feature on SO. I am talking about searching you on users and reading your answers to the posts. Which book do you refer as best for Swift ? I need to purchase book on Swift.It would be great help sir.@  vadian